# How to change the border color/size of the UITableView's sections in Grouped UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I need to change the color and the size of the border of each section in Grouped TableView in IOS. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can see [PrettyKit](https://github.com/vicpenap/PrettyKit) =>PrettyTableViewCell